# React JS system for creating template components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would need to create a structure in the src directory with the possibility of displaying an individual component for a specific user. For example, there would be a MyComponent component. By default, this component would be used, but I would need a solution to best set up a different body for this component for a particular user.

The default components could have the path **src/components/MyComponent**

and another component for users with the path **src/themes/user1/components/MyComponent**

If the path to the component did not exist in the themes directory, the default would be used, and if it existed, the component from themes would be used.

Can you think of a solution to this idea? So far, dynamic importing has been considered, but it is probably not the ideal solution. Thank you

Comment: So if you have 1 million users, then you have 1 million React components?

Comment: @goto1 Not all users should have their themes components. These would be exceptions to those users. Maybe 50 users out of 5000 could have an individual component.